# Looping through a data frame of datetimes

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse, lubridate

I'm trying to create GPS schedules for satellite transmitters that are used to track the migration of a bird species I'm studying. The function below called 'sched_gps_fixes' takes a vector of datetimes and writes them to a .ASF file, which is uploaded to the satellite transmitter. This tells the transmitter what date and time to take a GPS fix. Using R and the sched_gps_fixes function allows me to quickly create a GPS schedule that starts on any day of the year. The software that comes with the transmitters does this as well, but I would have to painstakingly select each time and date I want the transmitter to take a GPS location.

So I want to: 1) create a data frame that contains every day of the year in 2018, and the time I want the transmitter to collect a GPS location, 2) use each row of the data frame as the start date for a sequence of datetimes (so starting on 2018-03-25 12:00:00 for example, I want to create a GPS schedule that takes a GPS point every other day after that, so 2018-03-25 12:00:00, 2018-03-27 12:00:00, etc.), and 3) create a .ASF file for each GPS schedule. Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish below:

```
library(lubridate)

# set the beginning time
start_date <- ymd_hms('2018-01-01 12:00:00')

# create a sequence of datetimes starting January 1
days_df <- seq(ymd_hms(start_date), ymd_hms(start_date+days(10)), by='1 days')
tz(days_df) <- "America/Chicago"
days_df <- as.data.frame(days_df)
days_df

# to reproduce the example
days_df <- structure(list(days_df = structure(c(1514829600, 1514916000, 
1515002400, 1515088800, 1515175200, 1515261600, 1515348000, 1515434400, 
1515520800, 1515607200, 1515693600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "America/Chicago")), .Names = "days_df", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")

# the data frame looks like this:

days_df
1  2018-01-01 12:00:00
2  2018-01-02 12:00:00
3  2018-01-03 12:00:00
4  2018-01-04 12:00:00
5  2018-01-05 12:00:00
6  2018-01-06 12:00:00
7  2018-01-07 12:00:00
8  2018-01-08 12:00:00
9  2018-01-09 12:00:00
10 2018-01-10 12:00:00
11 2018-01-11 12:00:00
```

I would like to loop through each datetime in the data frame, and create a vector for each row of the data frame. So each vector would have a particular row's datetime as the starting date for a GPS schedule, which would take a point every 2 days (something like this):

```
[1] "2018-01-01 12:00:00 UTC" "2018-01-03 12:00:00 UTC" "2018-01-05 12:00:00 UTC" "2018-01-07 12:00:00 UTC"
[5] "2018-01-09 12:00:00 UTC" "2018-01-11 12:00:00 UTC"
```

Each vector (or GPS schedule) would then be run in the following function as 'gps_schedule' to create a .ASF file for the transmitters:

```
sched_gps_fixes(gps_schedule, tz = "America/Chicago", out_file = "./gps_fixes")
```

So I'm wondering how to create a for loop that would produce a vector of datetimes for each day of 2018. This is pseudocode for what I'm attempting to do:

```
# create a loop called 'create_schedules' to make the GPS schedules and produce a .ASF file for each day of 2018

create_schedules <- function(days_df) {

  for(row in 1:nrow(days_df)) {

    seq(ymd_hms(days_df[[i]]), ymd_hms(days_df[[i]]+days(10)), by='2 days')

  }
}

# run the function
create_schedules(days_df)
```

I'm guessing I need an output to store and name each vector by its start date, among other things?

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: Thanks for adding the details of the `data.frame`.  I'm not sure what output you expect at the end? Mainly `create a vector for each row of the data frame` is more confusing. Could you please explain it a bit?

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't explain that well. So I think what I would need is a vector for each day of the year. So a GPS schedule that starts on 2018-01-01, one that starts on 2018-01-02, etc., like this:

    2018-01-01_schedule<- [1] "2018-01-01 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-03 12:00:00 CST" ...

    2018-01-02_schedule<- [1] "2018-01-02 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-04 12:00:00 CST" ...

Comment: Will time be fixed for all days? Or do you expect time to be different for schedule of each day? Actually I am not sure why you need so many parallel schedule?

Comment: @Jason how many dates each vector should have? You have shown `"2018-01-01 12:00:00 UTC" "2018-01-03 12:00:00 UTC" "2018-01-05 12:00:00 UTC" "2018-01-07 12:00:00 UTC"
"2018-01-09 12:00:00 UTC" "2018-01-11 12:00:00 UTC"` for the first one, so each vector will include 6 dates?

Comment: @MKR I would like a schedule for each day because we may catch a bird and attach a satellite transmitter to it any day of the year. That way we can easily upload the GPS schedule from a list of schedules that starts on the particular day that we catch a bird.

Comment: @Antonis I simplified the example here, but each vector would contain 75 dates in it as that is how many points the satellite transmitters can take before the battery dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `mapply` to generate schedule for each row based on schedule definition provided by OP:

```
library(lubridate)

# For the sample data max_date needs to be calculated. Otherwise to generate
# schedule for whole 2018 max_date can be taken as 31-Dec-2018.
max_date = max(days_df$days_df)

mapply(function(x)seq(x, max_date, by="2 days"),days_df$days_df) 

#Result : Only first 3 items from the list generated. It will continue 
# [[1]]
# [1] "2018-01-01 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-03 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-05 12:00:00 CST"
# [4] "2018-01-07 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-09 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-11 12:00:00 CST"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "2018-01-02 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-04 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-06 12:00:00 CST"
# [4] "2018-01-08 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-10 12:00:00 CST"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "2018-01-03 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-05 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-07 12:00:00 CST"
# [4] "2018-01-09 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-11 12:00:00 CST"
# ....
# ....
# ....
# [[10]]
# [1] "2018-01-10 12:00:00 CST"
# 
# [[11]]
# [1] "2018-01-11 12:00:00 CST"
```

If OP prefers to have `names` for items in result list then `mapply` can be used as:

**Update:** Based on OP's request to generate schedule for start+10 days. 10 days is equivalent to `10*24*3600 seconds`.

```
mapply(function(x, y)seq(y, y+10*24*3600, by="2 days"),
    as.character(days_df$days_df), days_df$days_df, 
    SIMPLIFY = FALSE,USE.NAMES = TRUE) 

#Result
# $`2018-01-01 12:00:00`
# [1] "2018-01-01 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-03 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-05 12:00:00 CST"
# [4] "2018-01-07 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-09 12:00:00 CST" "2018-01-11 12:00:00 CST"
#.......
#.......
#.......so on
```

Comment: this is getting close to what I'm after, but I want the schedules to be the same number of days. In the list above, [[11]] only contains one date. I tried modifying your code so that max date was equal to the start date plus 10 days, but that didn't seem to do what I wanted either...

Comment: @Jason That's pretty simple. I can modify my answer so that it will do the job as you requested. Let me write a separate function to make it clear.

Comment: @Jason Have a look